# Parent class define static class for child class

Tags: java, class, inheritance, static, abstract

Wondering if there is a way to do this in Java.

Imagine I want to make a parent class (maybe abstract) and create multiple distinct child classes. I want all classes to have a certain field, but I need that field to be static *in the child context.* Is there a way I can define this in the parent class?

For example assume I have getters and setters for the field named Foo. In the parent class, the static field is initialized as the string "foo". I have two child classes AbsChildOne and AbsChildTwo. What I would like to be able to do is:

```
    AbsChildOne absOneA = new AbsChildOne();
    AbsChildOne absOneB = new AbsChildOne();
    AbsChildTwo absTwo = new AbsChildTwo();

    absOneA.setFoo("bar");
    System.out.println("absOneB "+absOneB.getFoo());
    System.out.println("absTwo "+absTwo.getFoo());
```

to return

```
absOne2 bar
absTwo foo
```

In other words, the static field is only static to the child class, but not other child classes.

Comment: One simple question, why need an instance (`new`)  and a method to set up a `static` field ? Wonder if it's very clear to you what `static` is intend to ...

Comment: @TraianGEICU I need the static to be at the subclass level because I am using JUnit which re-instantiates the test class for each test method in the class, and I am planning to use the same parent class for multiple multi-method test classes. If the static stays at the parent class, it will "bleed" into other subclasses, which is undesirable.

In the end I ended up just doing subclass statics and a custom interface for the getter methods to "enforce" their presence.

Comment: In retrospect I suppose a static @beforeclass method that clears the static parent field would work... but that would still have to be implemented within the subclasses, I think.

Comment: inherit a static field is useless for your purpose since always will be 1 value for all instances/subclasses/parent regardless from where is coming. updated. Just take a look of detailed answer and see if may get something useful for you. Also another option is to think maybe to redesign test-cases ... (the point is to try to keep as simple as could be code, tes-cases)

Answer (score 1):

The fact is that `static` is at class-level so each time would have one value for each `classes` includes `subclasses`(do not confuse with class-instance). So when using static (even init) do not require to have an instance.(`new`)

`String s_get_static_value = ClassName.value`. Each time for each `ClassName_instances` it will be only 1 value at one point at time which apply for all `instances`. So once changed (at class level, instance) will reflect to all instances(implied class level).

The point is that you cannot keep 2 separate static derived from same static (always have 1 value not 2).

Now if wanted to have an extended field parent with individual values per children(and just 1 at class level and all instances derived from a `Type`. `Type` can be also a subclass which is a distinct one. `Parent_Type` is not the same as `Child_type` even if `Child` extends `Parent` ).

Consider to chance the logic.(requirements : same as yours but without static)

```
//in term of field_value ; all in the same time and just 1 based on Types
parent = A (on Parent class) : Type Parent
parent = A1 (on Child1 at inhereted field from Parent) : Type Child1 
parent = A2 (on Child2 at inhereted field from Parent) : Type Child2

//oneInstance is doing that task which is an object based on Singleton
//can hold as may parameters as wanted (mystring in this case)
```

Maybe this could help you.

```
//adjusted singleton with a map which hold instances
import java.util.HashMap;

import tst.Test02.Child1;
import tst.Test02.Child2;

public class OneInstance 
{
    String myString = "";
    private OneInstance oi ;
    public static HashMap<String, OneInstance> hm = new HashMap<String,OneInstance>();
    public static OneInstance getInstance(Object o)
    {
        if(!hm.containsKey(o.getClass().toString()))
            hm.put(o.getClass().toString(), new OneInstance("default value for _"+o.getClass().toString()));
        return hm.get(o.getClass().toString());
        
    }
    public static OneInstance getInstance(Object o,String s)
    {
        if(!hm.containsKey(o.getClass().toString()))
            hm.put(o.getClass().toString(), new OneInstance(s));
        return hm.get(o.getClass().toString());
        
    }
    public static OneInstance getInstance()
    {
        if(!hm.containsKey(new Parent().getClass().toString()))
            hm.put(new Parent().getClass().toString(), new OneInstance("default value for Parent"));
        return hm.get(new Parent().getClass().toString());
    }
    
    private OneInstance() {}
    private OneInstance(String s)
    {
        
        myString = s;
    }
    
}
```

---

```
public class Parent 
{
    static MyObj sobj = new MyObj("static name");
    OneInstance oi;
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "myString="+oi.getInstance().myString;
    }
}
```

---

```
//usage
import java.util.Set;

public class Test02 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test02 t = new Test02();
        Child1 c1;
        Child2 c2;
        System.out.println("inhereted name for child1:"+Child1.sobj.name);
        Child1.sobj.name = "child1_new_name";
        System.out.println("child1 new name:"+Child1.sobj.name);
        System.out.println("inhereted name for child2:"+Child2.sobj.name);
        System.out.println("-----------");
        System.out.println(new Parent());
        c1 = t.new Child1("child1_string");
        
        //with any specification just init with parent value and keep
        System.out.println(c1);
        System.out.println(c1.oi.getInstance(c1).myString);
        System.out.println("-----------");
        
        System.out.println("dump HashMap");
        OneInstance.hm.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println((k + ":" + v.myString)));
        System.out.println("-----------");
        c2 = t.new Child2("child2_string from constructor"); 
        c1.oi.getInstance(c1).myString = "changed for child 1";
        System.out.println(c1.oi.getInstance(c1).myString);
        System.out.println("dump HashMap");
        OneInstance.hm.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println((k + ":" + v.myString)));
        System.out.println("-----------");
        c2 = t.new Child2("child2_string from constructor"); 
        System.out.println(c2);
        
        //System.out.println(c2.oi.getInstance(c2).myString);
        //c2.oi.getInstance(c2).myString = "changed for child 2";
        //System.out.println(c2.oi.getInstance(c2).myString);
        
        System.out.println(c1);
        System.out.println(c1.oi.getInstance(c1).myString);
        System.out.println(c2.oi.getInstance(c2).myString);
        System.out.println("dump HashMap");
        OneInstance.hm.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println((k + ":" + v.myString)));
        System.out.println("-----------");
        
        
    }
    
    class Child1 extends Parent
    {
         //inherited
         //OneInstance oi ;
         Child1(String s)
         {
             oi = OneInstance.getInstance(this, s);
         }
         public String toString()
         {
            return "myString="+oi.getInstance(this).myString;
         }
    }
    
    class Child2 extends Parent
    {
         //OneInstance oi ;
         Child2(String s)
         {
             oi =OneInstance.getInstance(this, s);
         }
         public String toString()
         {
            return "myString="+oi.getInstance(this).myString;
         }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
inhereted name for child1:static name
child1 new name:child1_new_name
inhereted name for child2:child1_new_name
-----------
myString=default value for Parent
myString=child1_string
child1_string
-----------
dump HashMap
class tst.Test02$Child1:child1_string
class tst.Parent:default value for Parent
-----------
changed for child 1
dump HashMap
class tst.Test02$Child1:changed for child 1
class tst.Test02$Child2:child2_string from constructor
class tst.Parent:default value for Parent
-----------
myString=child2_string from constructor
myString=changed for child 1
changed for child 1
child2_string from constructor
dump HashMap
class tst.Test02$Child1:changed for child 1
class tst.Test02$Child2:child2_string from constructor
class tst.Parent:default value for Parent
-----------
```

Regarding testing,  before is code-development. If there are logic-faults in code then what to expect from testing ? (entire test-suite will fail and have some critical defects to solve before being able to continue ...)
Fine to know various settings for a testing api _ junit but this was not the main scope. Code design to run properly and not code design for testing purpose.
(main issue coming from code design `static` and not from `how to test`)

Note: You have to add some logic to adjust based on inheritance (keep the field) but why not change the logic and allow another distinct-field for children ?
It will made much easily to implement and could use static as well.

```
class Parent 
{
   static String parent;
}
class Child1 extends Parent 
{
   //inhereted
   //static String parent;

   //add a new one per subclasses
   static String child1;
}
```

Just compare the lines of codes needed for each scenarios and ask if it really worth ? Metrics (even within lines of codes) counts also in quality-code.

Comment: To clarify, I don't write app code, I write test code for other apps.

I beginning to think I would have to have a static map that keys on the child class, as you suggest here.

I feel like I ought to be able to do something like

`class Parent {  
        public void getStatic() {   
            System.out.println(this.getClass().<static field name>);   
        }  
    }`

And if called from an object of child class `class ChildA extends Parent` it would give me the static of ChildA class, and likewise from another child class ChildB give me the static of ChildB class.

Comment: No issue from your side of responsibility. The question was related development(how to do something) and the short answer was you cannot with static. Now if want to test something that is something else.(but even here you cannot pass language capabilities). So again even for testing initial idea with an inherited static field cannot work properly (and even with small trick could be a mess). Regarding using a static map with keys on child class/obj that could work (it's up to you how write TCs, but even here writing TC_scripts do not involve passing code-design: work the same even if dev/tester

Comment: Script TC design (java with junit, etc) is the same as software-dev, dev concepts do not change, that wanted to pointed out.

Comment: The trick here was to use an object as parameter (so can hold as many other params wanted) and use a Map to hold  various instance type (mainly just 1 instance for a type) ...  if think is usefull for you, use it ... (but first run small tests to be sure you get expected output)

Comment: I was thinking that parameterized class would also work e.g. <T extends Parent> and encapsulate the object, thinking it would then refer to the object's native class rather than the superclass, but that didn't seem to work either; the static got masked and simply disappeared after the method.

Anyway thanks for the advice. I ended up going another way in the end, with the statics explicitly defined in the child classes and abstract getters/setters implemented in the subclasses. Less reuse than I'd hoped.

Comment: I brought up that this is a test to explain my scope is entirely JUnit which is why the static usage was desired; in order to have data points shared among methods in a class, they need to be static. It's made me realize we probably should be using something else, but it's a bit late for that decision.

Comment: `<T extends Parent>` do not think it will change something here ... but looking from multiple perspective is something to be appreciated. `static` is also powerful, but if know where and how to use it. Fine with junit and purpose (no issue here) ... but be sure in the end you get the expected results if not maybe something have to be changed. Good Luck !

Comment: also maybe if update the question to the purpose ...